# WPF attached behavior triggering after button click

Tags: wpf, behavior

I have the following class / behavior which is being called on button click event. The issue is that it gets called after button_click event. How to call it before button click event?
The below mentioned style is defined in App.xaml for global usage

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="local:DefaultButtonBehaviour.DefaultButton" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

**CODE:**

```
public static class DefaultButtonBehaviour
{
    /// 1. This is the boolean attached property with its getter and setter:
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        (
            "DefaultButton",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DefaultButtonBehaviour),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnDefaultButtonPropertyChanged)
        );
    public static bool GetDefaultButton(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DefaultButtonProperty);
    }
    private static void SetDefaultButton(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DefaultButtonProperty, value);
    }

    /// 2. This is the change event of our attached property value:
    ///     * We get in the first parameter the dependency object to which the attached behavior was attached
    ///     * We get in the second parameter the value of the attached behavior.
    ///     * The implementation of the behavior is to check if we are attached to a textBox, and if so and the value of the behavior
    ///       is true, hook to the PreviewGotKeyboardFocus of the textbox.
    private static void OnDefaultButtonPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ButtonBase button = dpo as ButtonBase;
        if (button != null)
        {
            if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            {
                button.Click += OnDefaultButtonClick;
            }
            else
            {
                button.Click -= OnDefaultButtonClick; ;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnDefaultButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonBase btn = (ButtonBase)sender;
        DependencyObject focusScope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(btn);
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(focusScope, btn);
        Keyboard.Focus(btn);
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you differentiate 'before' and 'after' of a click? Click is event and all handlers are called once event already occurred, you would need crystal ball to call them before event has occurred. Im probably not getting your question

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have a button click event in one of the screens. The button click gets fired first and then this behavior gets called. I want it the other way around.

Comment: Sorry,Im still not following, lets say you don't attach any behavior to click, what happens on click in your case then?

Comment: @sskher can you tell us, what this behavior will do?

Answer (score 0):

If I am following the question properly, you could approach this by wiring up the `Preview` events.  Hook into [PreviewMouseDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PreviewKeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) (so you can handle the case where the user uses the return key to activate the button).

Comment: The problem with PreviewKeyDown is that it will get triggerred for every keystroke and I want to avoid that

Comment: @sskher - You only need to look for specific keys though, so you can just check what key was pressed, and if it is a key you need, handle it, otherwise just let it bubble on up.

Comment: @sskher - Also, your hook will only trigger for keystroke when your button has focus, not when some other control has focus.  Also, I don't know of any other way to handle an event before the click event fires without handling the preview events or hooking into the mouse over or some other events that would occur before a click. The problem with those is that you don't know if a click will occur, but with mousedown and keydown you can be confident a click is occurring.